# Can WinRT application use obfuscation?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, obfuscation

All Metro applications must be inspected before distribution through Windows 8 AppStore. Does this mean it will not be allowed to use code obfuscation? Or it is still possible, and only some specific aspects are going to be monitored during such inspection?

Comment: Interesting question. You're supposed to be able to write WinRT apps in C++, which is a whole lot less decompilable than .NET, but that would also make it harder for the AppStore to verify that the apps are safe.

Comment: I think the real question is: "will obfuscator vendors update their product to support the app store".  And the answer is "of course!"

Comment: Just to confirm: YES! I work with PreEmptive Solutions on Dotfuscator. Windows store applications is definitely a targeted platform for us, and I assume for other obfuscator products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some facts:

- Marketplace for WP7 allows C# apps be obfuscated (even MS he advises
  doing so) and I don't see any reason why Windows AppStore would ban
  such apps.
- It is almost certain that some vendors will provide compatible C++
  obfuscator.
- You should care about your clients not crackers. :)
- a lot of hacks for code obfuscation will be banned.

**Remember, if you have some logic that you want to hide, make a webservice and consume it in your client app. Better spend your time building better app, fixing bugs etc.**

No dice, if someone has access to the binaries is just a matter of time when someone cracks it.

Comment: You should care about your clients not crackers?

Comment: Jerry Nixon, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. I think you are asking what a cracker is and it's like a safe-cracker/hacker. cracking is a p-ir'-ate word

Answer (score 5):

This is an armchair answer with some things that come to mind:

1. Even a C++ application can still be anazlyed if it depends on dynamic linking to a runtime or API, which is the case with WinRT applications. Microsoft approval can in theory include automated or human guided testing of your app using a special sandbox and/or OS hooks capable of detecting if your application attempts certain prohibited operations.
2. Under the hood, C++ apps for WinRT are more like native C++ apps than C++/CLI, so obfuscation is not needed to the degree that it is for C#, all things being equal.
3. You can still build C# apps that target WinRT, but your code will still be compiled to CIL and run within the CLR (more or less), invoking WinRT through wrappers that Microsoft provides. Because it's CIL, the question of obfuscation should be equivalent to that of C#/.NET obfuscation in general.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation is still possible for WinRT. The inspection made by the Application Certification Kit cover lot of aspects including metadata and IL verification. Just like the old peverify did.