# How can I protect the source of my HTML Metro app?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm really interested in building applications in a Windows 8 Metro style. I would like to use HTML5 but I am very concerned about protecting my front end UI from deconstruction and ultimately being ripped off by others. Unfortunately, my service is all open source so I cannot really hide things there unless i implement some sort of middle man between the open source service and my front end HTML5 app.

So as the title says, how do I protect the source of my HTML Metro Application?

Comment: It is not possible to protect the client app.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520871/can-winrt-application-use-obfuscation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Run a JavaScript obfuscator over your code.  This will make it much harder to figure out, but not impossible.
2. Implement the critical functions as C++ methods.  You can call these using WinRT easily from JavaScript.  This will make it much harder to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I delayed giving you the badge hoping others may be able to seek a solution to my issue. Anyways I've now accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep something (anything) secret, do NOT pass it to the client.

There might be some kind of obfuscation that I don't know about (yet) but still it will be possible to reconstruct the code.